# How to update ListView after Flutter beta 2 update

Tags: dart, flutter

The code below is a simplified version of the original, where my goal is to have a list of list tiles: List where I can keep track of newly created ListTile Widgets and which I can use as an argument to pass to a ListView.

```
class Notes extends StatefulWidget{

  _NotesState createState() => new _NotesState();
}

class _NotesState extends State<Notes>{

  List<ListTile> notes =[];

  void addNewNote(){
     setState((){
        notes.add(new ListTile(title: new Text("Broccolli")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return new Scaffold(
       appBar: new AppBar(title: "NOTES"),
       body: new Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
        // The notes
        new Container(
          child: new ListView(
            children: new List.from(notes, growable: false),
          )
        ),
        // The add notes button
        new FloatingActionButton(
          tooltip: 'Add a note',
          onPressed: addNewNote, 
        )
       ],
      ),
     );
  }
```

This used to work just fine before the last update to flutter where Dart 2 was introduced, but now I receive the following message:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' where
  List is from dart:core
  List is from dart:core
  Widget is from package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart
```

The issue stems from: new List.from(notes, growable: false)

My reason for doing this is because when I just pass the list as an argument to ListView.children flutter does not register a change and the new elements of the list are not displayed, so I just create a new List and my issue was resolved. However this is no longer viable

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the type of your `List` created by `new List.from` or else it defaults to `dynamic`.

The fact is that with strong-mode, `List<dynamic>` is not assignable to `List<whatever>` anymore. So you must make sure your `List` has the correct type.

In your case a simple `new List<Widget>.from(notes)` will do the trick